# divergence equation with prescribed normal trace

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a smooth domain and $\nu$ be the outer unit normal to $\partial \Omega$. Given $\phi \in L^{\infty}(\partial \Omega)$ such that $\int_{\partial \Omega} \phi d\sigma=0$ where $\sigma$ is the surface measure of $\partial \Omega$, we consider the divergence equation with prescribed $L^{\infty}$ normal trace $\phi$: 
$$\begin{cases} div F =0 \quad &\mbox{in $\Omega$}\\
F \cdot \nu=\phi \quad & \mbox{on $\partial \Omega$}.
\end{cases}$$
Is there any hope to show there exists a solution $F$ such that $||F||_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)} \le C(n)||\phi||_{L^{\infty}(\partial \Omega)}$? Can the constant $C(n)$ be equal to $1$?  If the above are not true, how about the possibility we could further relax the constant $C$ to be dependent on $n$ and only the surface area of $\partial \Omega$?

At first glance, if we let $F=\nabla u$, then the above equation becomes
$$\begin{cases} \Delta u=0 \quad &\mbox{in $\Omega$}\\
\partial_{\nu} u=\phi \quad & \mbox{on $\partial \Omega$}.
\end{cases}$$Such solution $u$ cannot be expected such that $|\nabla u| \le C(n)||\phi||_{L^{\infty}(\partial \Omega)}$ because usually it should depend on certain parameters of domain $\Omega$. So this approach does not work.

I'm not familiar with equations of divergence form with prescribed normal trace. Any references, comments or ideas are really appreciated.

Comment: If you consider two large domains one of which with positiv outflux and one with negativ outflux and connect them by a thin pipe than the flow in the pipe must be much larger than at the surface of the two large domains. Hence the constant must depend on the domain.

Comment: and by making the pipe thinner and thinner it follows that the constant does not only depend on the surface area.

Comment: @user35593, could you elaborate why as the pipe thinner and thinner the speed getting larger and larger?

Comment: The flow throgh the pipe is equal to the difference of the inflow of the two bodies. The flow through pipe is bounded by the area of  cross-section times infinity-norm of Flow

Comment: @user35593, thank you very much!